# Designer widget shadow?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, qtstylesheets

I have added a widget in my mainwindows and I would like to give it a show something like `box-shadow: 3px 3px 25px #111;`

I tried above by going to widget `change stylesheet` option and adding the code as below:

```
background-color:#fff;
border:4px solid blue;
box-shadow: 0px -3px 5px #a6a6a6;
```

The first two attribute give the expected effect but box-shadow don't work.

How to use Python QT Designer and add box shadow to a widget?

Answer (score 3):

Qt StyleSheet is not CSS but it is a technology that implements some features, and among them is not the box-shadow. If you want to implement something similar then you should use QGraphicsDropShadowEffect:

```py
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QPoint, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QGraphicsDropShadowEffect,
    QMainWindow,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QWidget,
)


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    main_window = QMainWindow()

    container = QWidget()
    container.setContentsMargins(3, 3, 3, 3)
    main_window.setCentralWidget(container)

    widget = QWidget()
    widget.setAutoFillBackground(True)

    lay = QVBoxLayout(container)
    lay.addWidget(widget)

    effect = QGraphicsDropShadowEffect(
        offset=QPoint(3, 3), blurRadius=25, color=QColor("#111")
    )
    widget.setGraphicsEffect(effect)

    main_window.resize(640, 480)
    main_window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

It is recommended that you read the Qt Stylesheet references:

- https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html
- https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html